# Font doesn't show on iPhone in Safari

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone, safari

My font does not display in Safari on my iPhone. I can select and copy the text but I don't see anything?

Here is the font-face code I am using:

```
@font-face {font-family:'TheSerifBoldPlain'; src: url('fonts/TheSerifBoldPlain.eot'); src: url('fonts/TheSerifBoldPlain.eot') format('embedded-opentype'), url('fonts/TheSerifBoldPlain.woff2') format('woff2'), url('fonts/TheSerifBoldPlain.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/TheSerifBoldPlain.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/TheSerifBoldPlain.svg#TheSerifBoldPlain') format('svg');font-weight: normal;font-style: normal;}
```

It only doesn't work on iPhone.

Comment: I would recommend to change all of the names of font files to lowercase, then update css. As I read in the other post, mobile safari is case sensitive when it comes to resources while desktop isn't so try to do that.

Answer (score 1):

i think is because of the .eot extension of your font
please check this

```
http://caniuse.com/#search=eot
```

using woff is better because it supports different browsers